# How to capture the right click event in Context Menu of Mail Item in Outlook 2016?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

When you right click a mail item in Outlook and select one of the buttons from Context Menu like Reply, the reply message is for the right-clicked mail item and not for the one that is selected by the inspector.

I have created a VSTO add-in and added a button to the mail item context menu, but I cant see to figure out how to run the add-in on the mail item that was right-clicked. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your code processing the menu item click event handler? The Context parameter will be the `Selection` object containing the item the user right clicks on.

Comment: That is exactly my question, I could not find any reference for the right click event handler. I added the method to the Context Menu of mail items using xml.

Comment: Doesn't your XML specify the onAction callback?